# Do I need to fully process dimension?

Tags: ssas, olap, dimensions

I have a shared dimension in SQL Server Analysis Services 2000. The dimension is used in two cubes. The dimension is marked as non-changing dimension.

Names of some memebers in the database have changed. However no structal changes have been made. I process the dimension incrementaly, but the names of the memebrs stored in dimension don't change.

Is the only option for me to fully process the dimension? I don't want to do it, because it would require reporocessing two very large cubes (30 GB cubes, and 300 GB of raw fact data).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have a similar solution working on SSAS 2005, and the Process Update option is working, that means name of memebers are changing.

Comment: So is it still an issue or not?

Comment: No, I moved the cubes into the SSAS 2005. This helped :)